# Find Max&Min Value in a dictionary of dictionaries (JSON) in python

Tags: python

I want to find the largest value in a JSON file, using python (so it would be a dictionary).
My JSON has this shape:

```
[{
  "probability": 0.623514056,
  "boundingBox": { "left": 36, "top": 1, "width": 403, "height": 95 }
},
{
  "probability": 0.850905955,
  "boundingBox": { "left": 42, "top": 200, "width": 412, "height": 90 }
},
{
  "probability": 0.308903724,
  "boundingBox": { "left": 79, "top": 309, "width": 690, "height": 125 }
}]
```

And I want to find the maximum and the minimum width. And doing 2 "for"s would take a lot of time (since the JSON is larger than the showed here). Is there an optimal way to do that? like max(*something*)

So the output I would like would be:

```
Max Width: 690
Min Width: 403
```

Comment: Whether you iterate twice (once for max, once for min) shouldn't be any different from iterating once and doing twice the work each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution is probably:

```
widths = [d['boundingBox']['width'] for d in json_file]
min_value = min(widths)
max_value = max(widths)
```

However, `min` and `max` just use loops under the hood, which you mentioned may be slow.  Test the above solution first, and if that is too slow for your needs, you can combine the loops into one:

```
min_value, max_value = float('inf'), float('-inf')
for d in json_file:
    value = d['boundingBox']['width']
    if value < min_value:
        min_value = value
    if value > max_value:
        max_value = value
```

EDIT: Performance difference is negligible.  Go with the first one.

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> test = """\
... values = [v for v in x]
... min_value = min(values)
... max_value = max(values)
... """
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=test, number=10000, setup="""import numpy as np; x = np.random.rand(10000)""")
7.404742785263807
>>> test2 = """\
... min_value, max_value = float('inf'), float('-inf')
... for v in x:
...     value = v
...     if value < min_value:
...         min_value = value
...     if value > max_value:
...         max_value = value
... """
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=test2, number=10000, setup="""import numpy as np; x = np.random.rand(10000)""")
7.252437709830701
```

Comment: I'd be shocked if that second one is faster than the first.

Answer (score 1):

That's fairly easy to do:

```
max_width = max(d["boundingBox"]["width"] for d in dicts)
min_width = min(d["boundingBox"]["height"] for d in dicts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lambda function

```
max(data, key=lambda d: d['boundingBox']['width'])
min(data, key=lambda d: d['boundingBox']['width'])
```